# Define alias for blade directory in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How i can define blade directory in liravel ?

I wanna to use:

```
return view('panel::post.create');

// e.g : resurces/views/vendor/panel/post/create.blade.php
```

How i should define `vendor/panel`  as `panel::` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this using the service provider's `loadViewsFrom` method. The `loadViewsFrom` method accepts two arguments: the path to your view templates and your package's name. For example, if your package's name is panel, you would add the following to your service provider's boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'panel');
}
```

Package views are referenced using the `package::view` syntax convention. So, once your view path is registered in a service provider, you may load the admin view from the panel package like so:

```
Route::get('admin', function () {
    return view('panel::admin');
});
```

Read more at [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages#views).